# How to integrate webpack in a legacy-structure project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack

I created a small project in a "legacy manner" and I want to integrate webpack. The project is using angularjs and bootstrap.

I do not want to modify my code base. I bundle only js files.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main.js',
        others: ['...', '...']
        vendor: [
            'jquery',
            'bootstrap',
            'angular',
            'angular-route'
        ]
    },
    output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
       filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
]}
```

In the index.html I just include app.bundle.js, others.bundle.js and vendor.bundle.js.

The build works. But of course bootstrap js code will not be executed (so navbar toggle not working on small devices). Is there a way to make it work with bootstrap? Do I have to require/import bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/696)

Are you sure everything is alright with the reference to bootstrap from your
html file?

---

I just saw you wrote you didn't add a reference to bootstrap from your html.
I think that might be the problem